# How to configure webpack-bundle-analyzer for react?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-bundle-analyzer

I'm trying configure my webpack.config for webpack-bundle-analyzer. Here how it looks.

```
const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin;

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new BundleAnalyzerPlugin()
  ]
}
```

And it shows only index.js, main.js and src folders. How to see all my other dependencies?

[image]

Comment: Are you certain there are other dependencies being imported? Can you share some of the code?

Comment: @skovy I have no idea how to import dependencies, What kind of code would you like?

Comment: You asked `How to see all my other dependencies` so I assumed you were importing dependencies? The webpack bundle analyzer only visualizes code that is processed by webpack. If it's never imported (eg `import React from "react"`) it won't show up in the visualization. What's the webpack entrypoint? Is it importing anything or do you only have a single, mostly empty `main.js` and `src/index.js` files?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First 
npm install --save-dev webpack-bundle-analyzer
Second, add some config in webpack.config.js
Here's my config when using create react app in config/webpack.config.js

Import the library in the top

```
const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin;
```

Add also some validation so your build script doesn't have a problem when you deploy to production

```
const withReport = process.env.npm_config_withReport
```

Add this code inside plugins

```
plugins:[
  withReport ? new BundleAnalyzerPlugin() : '',
]
```

lastly, add a new script inside package JSON

```
"report": "npm run build --withReport true"
```

Go run "npm run report" in your terminal. should be automatically appear the webpack bundle analyzer UI

Answer (score 24):

If you're using [Create React App](https://create-react-app.dev/), a simpler method is to go to `package.json` and edit the npm scripts.

1. Run `npm install --save-dev webpack-bundle-analyzer` to install webpack-bundle-analyzer
2. Add a `--stats` flag at the end of `"build"` script command
3. Add a new script called `"analyze"` as shown below

```json
"scripts": {
  ...
  "build": "react-scripts build --stats",
  "analyze": "webpack-bundle-analyzer build/bundle-stats.json",
},
```

Next, run `npm run build` and then `npm run analyze`.

Answer (score 4):

This way you can configure `webpack-bundle-analyzer` **WITHOUT EJECTING** your React App

1. Add some dependencies by executing `npm install --save-dev progress-bar-webpack-plugin webpack-bundle-analyzer`
2. Create a new folder named `scripts` at the root of your React App.
3. Create a new file `analyze_build_bundle.js` in the `scripts` folder and add the below code in that file

```js
// script to enable webpack-bundle-analyzer
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production';
const webpack = require('webpack');
const { BundleAnalyzerPlugin } = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer');
const webpackConfigProd = require('react-scripts/config/webpack.config')(
  'production'
);

const ProgressBarPlugin = require('progress-bar-webpack-plugin');

webpackConfigProd.plugins.push(new BundleAnalyzerPlugin());
webpackConfigProd.plugins.push(
  new ProgressBarPlugin({
    format: `analyzing... [:bar] [:percent] [:elapsed seconds] - :msg`,
  })
);

// actually running compilation and waiting for plugin to start explorer
webpack(webpackConfigProd, (err, stats) => {
  if (err || stats.hasErrors()) {
    console.error(err);
  }
});
```

4. Add the `analyze-build-bundle` command in your `package.json` file to run the `webpack-bundle-analyzer` as below:

```js
"scripts": {
    "analyze-build-bundle": "node scripts/analyze_build_bundle.js",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    .....
    ...
}
```

5. Now execute command `npm run analyze-build-bundle`. This will build your app and then start the analyzer local server and you should be able to see the screen as shown in below image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To run the plugin with an optional parameter, for me, the solution presented on the following topic worked better:
[webpack config with optional usage of BundleAnalyzerPlugin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68824797/12525478)

> I fixed this by making a couple changes to my webpack.config.js.
>
> First I changed the way I declare withReport. Then I changed the way I
> instantiate BundleAnalyzerPlugin, to instead use concat after the
> other plugins:

```
...
const withReport = process.env.npm_config_withReport ? true : false;
...
plugins: [
...
].concat(withReport ? [new BundleAnalyzerPlugin()] : []),
...
```