# webpack config with optional usage of BundleAnalyzerPlugin

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-bundle-analyzer

I'm using webpack for a React project and would like to include the [WebpackBundleAnalyzer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-bundle-analyzer), but *only* when explicitly specified in the npm script (e.g., `npm run build --withReport true`). By default, I don't want it to run.

My build script in **package.json** is straightforward:

```
"build": "webpack --mode production",
```

As are are the relevant snippets from my **webpack.config.js**:

```
...
const withReport = process.env.npm_config_withReport || 'false';
...
plugins: [
  ...
  withReport ? new BundleAnalyzerPlugin() : '',
],
...
```

My thought is that `withReport` will be false unless I specify otherwise (e.g., `npm run build --withReport true`), thus the BundleAnalyzer will **not** execute if I leave that off (`npm run build`).

Instead, the analyzer executes even if I don't specify `--withReport`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by making a couple changes to my **webpack.config.js**.

First I changed the way I declare *withReport*. Then I changed the way I instantiate BundleAnalyzerPlugin, to instead use *concat* after the other plugins:

```
...
const withReport = process.env.npm_config_withReport ? true : false;
...
plugins: [
  ...
].concat(withReport ? [new BundleAnalyzerPlugin()] : []),
...
```